# Hibernate order of tables creation

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm

I can't find on the documentation any reference about how Hibernate decides the order in which it creates the tables defined in mapping.

I suspect it has a "smart" way based on table dependecies but I want to be sure first.